# javascript form validation using test

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I recently learnt this code but this code is not working as it is expected to .It is for form validation

```
function username_validation(name){
    var valid_name = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,30}$/;
    if(!valid_name.test(name)) 
     {         
         return false; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         return true;
     } 


}
```

Comment: This is just a function. How are you calling it?

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: What is the expectation? Whis will return true iff `name` is between 5 and 30 characters long, all alphanumeric or underscores.

Comment: what is "Expected to" and what do you mean by "not Working"..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must hook this function to an event listener.
Like :

```
<form onsubmit="username_validation(this.usernameTextfield.value);">
```

So this function will be triggered every time that particular form is submitted.
There's nothing wrong with your function.

The line :

```
var valid_name = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,30}$/;
```

creates a RegExp object.

Then :

```
valid_name.test(name)
```

checks if the `name` mathces with the `valid_name` pattern.
RegExp has a boolean method `test(s)` which returns true if the given string `s` matches with the RegExp pattern

A better way to write that would be :

```
function validate(name) {
    var r=/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,30}$/;
    return r.test(name);
}
```

Hope it helps...